# Update different users's session in ServiceStack

Tags: session, authentication, caching, servicestack

I am fairly new to ServiceStack and I'm working on a project that is based on it.

The project has admin panel and the admin is able to reset users passwords, update their info etc.

Session is kept in Azure Cache services using the AzureCacheClient provided with ServiceStack.

What I want is when the admin updates some user's info, that same update should reflect the cached IAuthSession object. I have access to the ICacheClient (of course), but how can I know the key under which each user's session is kept under?

Answer (score 3):

I have a scenario where I needed to do something similar.  My solution was to add an identifier to a session that related to the user through the CustomUserSession.

I then use a REDIS client and loop through all sessions until I find one with the user identifier, then perform whatever grab the sessions, perform whatever update and save the session again.

```
using (var redis = _appHost.TryResolve<IRedisClientsManager>().GetClient())
{
    var sessionkeys = redis.SearchKeys("urn:iauthsession:*");

    foreach (var key in sessionkeys)
    {
        var session = redis.Get<CustomUserSession>(key);
        if (session != null)
        {
           if (session.StudentId == SessionToFindId)
           {
               //Perform updates to session
               redis.Set(key, session);
           }
        }
     }                    
}
```